# Understanding Haskell Type Level Literals

Tags: haskell, types, infix-operator

Looking at the [Haskell Servant package](http://haskell-servant.github.io/), there is an initial example of defining a webservice API as:

```
             -- GET /date
type MyAPI = "date" :> Get '[JSON] Date
             -- GET /time/:tz
        :<|> "time" :> Capture "tz" Timezone :> Get '[JSON] Time
```

I'm having trouble understanding what this means and would appreciate an explanation for the following:

1. `:>` and `:<|>` are infix constructors. Does this type declaration mean that they are defined here or they are used here? Or maybe `:>` is defined here but `:<|>` is defined elsewhere? Or something else? Not sure how to read this type.
2. What is `'[JSON]`? Is this some sort of type-level literal list? What does the quote do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The (infix) constructors are used here, and they must be defined elsewhere in `data` or `newtype` declarations. `type` declarations do not produce constructors of any sort ever.

`'[JSON]` is indeed a type level list, equivalent to `JSON ': '[]`. The single quote indicates that a data constructor is being lifted to a type constructor. I'm not sure what deep significance that has, but at least it avoids confusion that might otherwise arise from the fact that data constructors and type constructors can share names.

Comment: Thanks. The GHC documentation on type-level literals say nothing about lists. Do you know where this is defined?

Comment: @Ana type-level versions of all promotable data types are automatically defined when the `DataKinds` extension is in use. [See here for details.](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/promotion.html)

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record, here are the actual definitions of `:<|>` and `:>`.

```
-- that's really like a pair of an 'a' and a 'b'...
-- that can be chained in a nice way, as opposed to nested pairs.
data a :<|> b = a :<|> b
data a :> b
```

The latter doesn't have any constructor because we don't need it when combining request handlers together, whereas we're reusing the `:<|>` symbol when we glue several request handlers together, at the value-level, as opposed to putting together descriptions for several endpoints at the type-level, where we also use the `:<|>` operator. In the latter case though, we're referencing `:<|>`-the-type-constructor, whereas when we're using it on handlers, we're referencing `:<|>`-the-data-constructor.